# Bootstrap nav-collapse hide in single page app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using 2.x Bootstrap version for my single-page application.

On the desktop, it works fine.

However on my ipad and mobile phones, it shows a nav button which is good. However, when I click an item in the dropdown item shown, it does not close automatically.

Since, it's a single page app, I find it annoying to click it again to hide to look at the contents.

I tried collapse('hide') when li is clicked on nav-collapse elements but it hides other li elements in the dropdown menus.

$('.nav-collapse > li').click(function(e)
$(this).collapse('hide')

What's the best way to hide when a link is clicked?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi cloudpre, I have encountered this issue and found a nice solution! See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in Twitter Bootstrap's Dropdown plugin (see [Issue #4497](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4497)) which was introduced in 2.1.0 and inadvertently blocks the click events on dropdown menu items.  It should be fixed in 2.1.1.

If you are using a CDN or simply don't want to edit/recompile the **bootstrap-dropdown.js**, you can just add the following workaround to your page, loading it after bootstrap:

```
$('body')
  .off('click.dropdown touchstart.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown')
  .on('click.dropdown touchstart.dropdown.data-api'
    , '.dropdown form'
    , function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
```

If you are hosting your own code, and are comfortable building the **bootstrap.min.js**, then you can make the following edit to **bootstrap-dropdown.js** on **line 145**:

```
'.dropdown'
```

should be changed to

```
'.dropdown form'
```

Comment: I am aware of this bug as it affected us too. However, I'm using older version. The question is more about various ways to hide the div after a link is checked on a single page applications.

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same issue as well, and solved it by adding data attributes (modified to collapse only the open .nav-collapse) to the nav item links themselves.

Note the data-target on the links is ".nav-collapse.in" which only selects the expanded nav, thereby acting as a close only.

For example:

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
    <!-- Collapse icon goes here -->
</a>

<div class="nav-collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse.in">Link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is tested in Bootstrap 2.2.1 on Mac OSX Chrome only. Although it is repetitive and not DRY, it does keep the collapsing declaration to the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

In Bootrap 3.3.4 you can add the following to the anchor tags to auto-close the nav.

data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"